# What do you call the battery slot's ends?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the battery slot's ends? By that, I mean the spring and the little round flat end for the plus and minus ends of the battery. Do they have a name? I looked up on the Internet, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are called *contacts*., or alternatively, *terminals*.

> A battery holder is a cavity or compartment used to house one or more
>   batteries in a piece of equipment safely. The battery holder has flat
>   metal or spring coiled contacts that press against the battery
>   terminals making an electrical contact.

[Battery holders and mounts (RS Components)](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/batteries/battery-chargers-battery-accessories/battery-holders-mounts/)

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest another word from your answer, which is _terminals_. I believe it can be used to refer to the contacts just as well as to the ends of the batteries.

Comment: My 2 cents: Terminals are the ends of the battery itself, while contacts are on the device. Using them interchangeably is acceptable, but less common in my experience.

Comment: Using 'positive and negative terminals' of e.g. a battery, DC generator or motor is very common.